# Фильтрация в Java

Tags: java, веб-служба, jersey

Всем привет! Я начинающий в использовании веб технологий в Java.. 
Наткнулся в интернете на этот код..Не могу понять, какой смысл в создании фильтров, например, как этот.

Не понятен метод `doFilter()` класса Filter Chain.. В документации пишется: 
Что этот метод:

> Causes the next filter in the chain to be invoked, or if the calling
>   filter is the last filter in the chain, causes the resource at the end
>   of the chain to be invoked

Возможно вопрос глупый но из за не понимания абсолютно данной темы хотел спросить: Какой следующий фильтр по очереди ? (Что значит разбудить как я понимаю при переводе на русский) "Следующий фильтр"? Любые примеры помогут для понимания самой идеи данного функционала..
Литература по теме если кто сможет посоветовать тоже поможет!

```
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
private FilterConfig filterConfig;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("doFilter is execute");

    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    //chain.doFilter(request, response);  
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    this.filterConfig = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Вообще, если вы хотите делать web на Java, сядьте и вдумчиво, неспешно прочитайте [спеку](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf). Там все подробно разобрано, что и для чего.

Comment: Почитаю спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Фильтры в Servlet API - это механизм, который позволяет:

- предварительно обработать запрос на определенные URL-ы, перед тем как он будет передан сервлету;
- и/или обработать ответ перед отдачей клиенту;
- либо же вернуть какой-то ответ принудительно.

Фильтрам как и сервлетам назначается маска URL-ов, для которых фильтр будет применяться. Например, `/*` или `/admin/*`. Кроме того, фильтры объявляются в определенном порядке.

Непосредственно обработка происходит в методе `doFilter()`, который вы должны реализовать. Т.к. фильтров, подходящих URL-у пришедшего запроса может оказаться несколько, они выстраиваются в цепочку (filter chain), согласно заданного порядка. Поэтому выполнив свою задачу, фильтр должен вызвать метод `chain.doFilter(request, response)`, чтобы протолкнуть запрос следующему получателю (фильтру или  конечному сервлету).

---

Типичные примеры использования фильтров:

- аутентификация и авторизация;
- обогащение запроса или ответа дополнительными заголовками;
- шифрование и сжатие;
- преобразование форматов данных;
- кеширование;
- модификация XML потоков.

Например, в веб-приложении абсолютно все запросы могут перекодироваться одним фильтром, а другой будет проверять доступ к защищенной части (например, к админке). Так часть запросов будут пропускаться через два фильтра, а остальные - только через один.

---

В вашем примере все запросы, которые пройдут через этот фильтр, будут безусловно перенаправлены на страницу `login.jsp`. Если бы в конце метода `doFilter()` было что-то такое:

```
if (userAuthorized()) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);  
} else { 
    httpResponse.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```

то получился бы простой фильтр авторизации, который отправлял запросы незарегистрированных пользователей на `login.jsp`, а остальные - пропускал.

Comment: Nofate Спасибо за твои ответы очень помогают.. \

Answer (score 1):

Фильтры - это Java-код, пригодный для повторного использования и позволяющий преобразовать содержание HTTP-запросов, HTTP-ответов и информацию, содержащуюся в заголовках HTML. Фильтр занимается предварительной обработкой запроса, прежде чем тот попадает в сервлет, и/или последующей обработкой ответа, исходящего из сервлета. Например, часто фильтры используют для установления кодировки в параметрах запроса и ответа.
Фильтры описываются в web.xml и привязываются к урлам запросов. Если одному урлу соответствует несколько фильтров, они будут применяться в порядке перечисления в web.xml Фильтр содержит методы init и destroy для инициализации/удаления фильтра и его параметров (при необходимости) и основного метода doFilter. Если фильтр применяется для некоторого урла, соответствующего некоторому сервлету, то запрос попадает в метод doFilterфильтра, там с ним что-либо делают, затем передают запрос дальше по цепочке (doFilter-метод) либо в следующий фильтр (если такой есть), либо на сервлет. После того, как сервлет возвратит response, последний по цепочке фильтров в обратную сторону выходит из методов doFilter и в конце отправляется клиенту.